# checking ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, netstat

If I have a tunnel opened with this command

```
 ssh -f root@localhost -g -L 60000:10.128.123.67:32354 -N
```

Which call of `netstat` do I have to use to see whether the tunnel is open or not?

I am working with Linux Red Hat.

Regards

Comment: Do you want to know if the tunnel is available, or whether there are any connections using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
netstat -anp | grep 60000.*ssh
```

should do the job.